# Visual Studio for Mac & .NET Core Web API with Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-mac

I just got a MacBook Pro and am trying to run a dotnet core web api project I created on my Windows PC. I also am learning how to use Docker and am trying to integrate it into my project.

When I right click on my API project and hit Add > Docker Support, a docker-compose project and corresponding .yml file are generated and a Dockerfile is added to my Api project.

This is what the .yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile
```

And here is the Dockerfile that is generated:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY AdamWebsiteApi.sln ./
COPY Api/Api.csproj Api/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

When I run the solution, using the docker-compose project as the startup, I get the following error:

```
Cannot start service api: Mounts denied: 
The path /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
```

Any idea what I need to do to get this working? It might be really simple and obvious but I am very new to Docker and Macs so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264180/visual-studio-for-mac-net-core-web-api-with-docker

Comment: I'm not on a mac, but I've seen similar errors on Windows 10.  Sounds like you need to go into the Docker preferences and enable shared paths that are requested in the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add the folder /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder to the File Sharing list in Docker Preferences. It will work.